# Button_to No route matches [GET] "/new_user_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, button-to

I am trying to get the page to be directed to the directory `users/new`, using a `button_to`
However everytime I click on it, it generates an error saying

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/new_user_path"

Here is my `application.html.haml` which contains the `button_to` I am talking about

```
%html

%head
%title Rotten Potatoes!
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
= csrf_meta_tags


%body
%h1.title Rotten Potatoes!

= button_to 'Sign Up/Login', 'new_user_path', :method => :get

#main
  - if flash[:notice]
    #notice.message= flash[:notice]
  - elsif flash[:warning]
    #warning.message= flash[:warning]

  = yield
```

Here is the result of my `rake routes`

```
    movies   GET    /movies(.:format)           movies#index
             POST   /movies(.:format)           movies#create
   new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)       movies#new
  edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)  movies#edit
       movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)       movies#show
             PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)       movies#update
             DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)       movies#destroy
       users GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
```

This is my `users_controller.rb` file if that helps

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
  @user=User.create_user!(params[:user])

      if !!(@user)
      flash[:notice] = "New user #{@user.user_id} was successfully created."
      redirect_to movies_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "The User Id #{params[:user][:user_id]} already exists"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end

end
```

Note that the `redirect_to new_user_path` (with the conditional statement) works perfectly fine.

Can you tell me where the problem lies? Also, I tried using `link_to` as well and it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Should the argument for button_to be the method `new_user_path()` instead of a string `'new_user_path'`?